# Multiple groups of dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery, how to get multiple dropdowns for each group of handset, for example:

Customer can select more than 1 handset to make an order. Firstly customer will need to select a number of handset from a dropdown (1 to 15).

If they have selected number 5 from a dropdown then 5 groups of dropdrowns should appear like this:

**Group One:**

```
Select Phone [Dropdown / load entries via ajax] 

Select Contract Length [Dropdown / load entries via ajax]

Select Contract Plan [Dropdown / load entries via ajax]

Select Additional Addon [Dropdown  / load entries via ajax]
```

**Group Two:**

`Same dropdowns as above`

Other question is, if there an error (validation from PHP) for not filling the form properly - it will redirect back same page but the dropdowns will need to be reselected again. How to make that to work also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you will have to bring some variable indicating the failure of form completion like into a session or some hidden element in html and then on document load - check for that variable and manually invoke those drop downs.

OR

Do not allow to click the submit button and check the validation in javascript. However it won't be that secure but it would save hassle for both you and the user. I myself would prefer form being checked before clicking submit just to wait a few seconds until the page is reloaded and I face the fact I chose/wrote something wrong.

OR

Validate automatically with xmlhttprequest or something similarly working so on submit click, js accesses php file, validates, returns the result and allows submission of data. Won't be super secure but... You can recheck that with the same php file again (will be caught if someone tried illegitimately pass some data not through form and xmlhttprequest failed to catch it). Would be safest and nicest way for the user.

Comment: Thanks for answering - I've understand the logic well. thanks... How to execute multiple group of drop downs when I select number of handset I want?

Comment: I guess you should just loop through all your dropdowns starting from the top level one and virtually chose what it selected. The key thing is that you have to save all the selections from highest to lowest dropdown, otherwise you won't be able to get it that easily. So after form submition, you have to take the handset so you know which one was chosen. Don't see other choice :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this markup:

```
<select id="qty">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

Use this JavaScript:

```
$('#qty').change(function() {
    var qty = $('#qty').val() * 1;

    $('#placeholder').html(''); //Clear existing.

    for (var i = 0; i < qty; i++)
    {
        $('#placeholder').append(
            '<select id="phone_' + i + '"></select>');
    }
});
```

In your PHP script you'll need to check each possible field name - potentially taxing, probably better to composite these into a hidden field before submitting.

And it looks like @AndriusNaruševičius has answered the other half of your question.